# Regarding Mobile Break Points for responsive design

Tags: mobile, web, responsive-design

Not a mobile design guy but have to work with some of my vendors who are making a mobile site for my company.

The visual design images they provided has 3 breakpoints. Basically lines which says how the site will look for 320px, 600px and 768px above.

Now when i asked my vendor which will show up for iphone 4 which has a resolution of 640 in portrait he says it will show 320 breakpoint. He showed me the following website which has a column called Device-W which he says should be used during development of the website.
http://screensiz.es/phone

Now the thing is before i go for the development vendor i wanted some one to help me understand what is that Device-W in laymans term so that am sure am not making any wrong decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml) should help you.

> device-width refers to the width of the device itself, in other words,
>   the screen resolution of the device. Most mobile phones have a device-width of
>   480px or lower, including the popular iPhone 4 (with device-width:
>   320px), despite it technically having a 640 x 960 resolution. This is
>   due to iPhone 4's retina display, which crams two device pixels into
>   each CSS pixel on the screen. This is true for the Ipad 3 as well; its
>   reported device-width is 768px just like its predecessors, even though
>   its actual screen resolution is 1536px x 2048px. In general width is
>   more versatile when it comes to creating responsive webpages, though
>   device-width is useful when you wish to specifically target mobile
>   devices (and not desktops with a small browser window for example), as
>   rarely do desktops have screen resolutions below a certain number such
>   as 320px x 480px.

Comment: Thanks. I now get an idea about it.